# Any reference material on the Franco-Benoni defense?

Tags: opening, theory, franco-benoni

The **Franco-Benoni defense** is characterized by the black moves:

```
[fen ""]
[startply "4"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 c5
```

The books I've read on the French defense contain none or very little information about this opening. Are there any "authoritative" or "main line" references or books that investigate this opening? Are any of you using this opening in your games? Where do you get your information from?

Comment: Note that if you play this as Black you'd better be ready to play a 2...e6 Open Sicilian after 3.Nf3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [a book on the Franco-Benoni](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0945470177). (Using the alternative name "Barcza-Larsen")

It's rather old (1991) but I would guess theory doesn't move that quickly in the Franco-Benoni. It's probably a good way to get started, but you might want to check the lines with an engine.

Edit: There is also [a short article by Harding](https://web.archive.org/web/20011019080242/http://www.chesscafe.com/text/kibitz13.txt) on chesscafe.com.